# Removing rows with Z score above 3

Tags: r, plyr

data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B20HmmYd0lsFbnE4RUh6N0xtUHc/edit?usp=sharing

Where dat$C, I want to remove items with RT of Z scores 3 or above for each sxS combination.

I had two ways (clean function and line using plyr package below) I thought I could do this, but one removes more rows than the other. Can somebody explain to me why my clean function does not agree with the line using plyr. package?

```
dat <- read.table(file="dat.txt")


# 3SD clean function
  clean <- function(df) {
 dfc <- df[as.logical(df$C),]
n=tapply(df$RT,list(df$s,df$S),length)
ns=tapply(df$RT,list(df$s),length)
mn=tapply(df$RT,list(df$s,df$S),mean)
sd=tapply(df$RT,list(df$s,df$S),sd)
upper <- mn+3*sd
bad <- logical(dim(df)[1])
levs <- paste(df$s,df$S,sep=".")
for (i in levels(df$s)) for (j in levels(df$S)) {
lev <- paste(i,j,sep=".")      
bad[levs==lev] <- df[levs==lev,"RT"] > upper[i,j]
}
df=df[!bad,]
nok=tapply(df$RT,list(df$s,df$S),length)
pbad=100-100*nok/n
print(aperm(round(pbad,1),c(2,1)))
nok=tapply(df$RT,list(df$s),length)
pbad=100-100*nok/ns
print(sort(round(pbad,1)))  
print(mean(pbad,na.rm=T))
df
}


require(plyr)
str(ddply(dat,.(s,S,C),function(x) x[scale(x$RT)< 3.00,]))
str(clean(dat))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not able to get your sample data.

Assuming you have zscore calculated already and put it into a data frame
You could simply say

```
 mydata[mydata$score <=3, ]
```

should be enough!